# How can I get GravityForms to stop adding it's script to specific pages with PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms, wordpress-plugin-creation

There are issues I'm having with GravityForms in WordPress adding it's script to each page, which looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">if(!gform){document.addEventListener("gform_main_scripts_loaded",function(){gform.scriptsLoaded=!0}),window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){gform.domLoaded=!0});
```

etc.

How can I make it so that this script doesn't get added on certain pages, using PHP? (with another plugin, for example)

I don't want to edit GravityForms code as this would obviously break if it was ever updated.

Surely there must be some way to hook in and change the behavior. So far I have looked into using `remove_filter` and `wp_deregister_script` but have not been successful so far.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue in Gravity Forms - details here: https://community.gravityforms.com/t/remove-unused-gf-script-from-header-resolved/9937

It was just recently patched, if you update to the latest build, should be fixed.